# How can I stop scanf-ing input after a certain character?

Tags: c, string

I'm working on a function that takes filepaths and dices them up into smaller sections.

For example, if the input parameter was "cd mypath/mystuff/stack/overflow/string", I want to be able to return "cd" "mypath", "mystuff", "stack", "overflow", and "string" in succession.

While I could simply continually use "getchar", appending the results to an ever-increasing string, stopping when getchar returns a '/', I feel like there *must* be a more elegant way to achieve the same functionality.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `char * strtok ( char * str, const char * delimiters );` using `/` as separator.

An example here:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s path\n", argv[0]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  char* saveptr = NULL;
  for (char* str = argv[1]; ; str = NULL) {
    char *token = strtok_r(str, "/", &saveptr);
    if (token == NULL) 
      break;
    printf("%s\n", token);
  } 

  return 0;
}
```

#### Example

```
clang -Wall *.c && ./a.out mypath/mystuff/stack/overflow/string
mypath
mystuff
stack
overflow
string
```

Comment: But please don't use `strtok` in production code; it's not re-entrant/threadsafe. If available on your platform, prefer `strtok_r` or `strsep` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how `sscanf()` can stop after a certain character.

```
sscanf("abcd/efgh", "%[^/]", &buf);
printf("%s\n", buf);
```

Should produce

```
abcd
```

EDIT: You could try something like this to advance sscanf() input.  I have not tested this for various edge cases, but it should get the idea across.

```
    char *str = "abcd/efgh/ijk/xyz";

    while (sscanf(str, "%[^/]%n", &buf, &n)) {
            printf("%s\n", buf);
            str += n;
            if (*str == '\0')
                    break;
            ++str;
    }
```

should produce

```
abcd
efgh
ijk
xyz
```

Comment: will successive sscanf calls start from where it stopped?

Comment: @Raven Dreamer - No.  Each successive sscanf call needs a different first argument.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using regcomp, regexec.  Compile and run it with the first arg being the character you are searching on, while the second arg is the string to search.

For example, a.out X abcXdefXghiXjkl will print  abc  def  ghi  jkl  on separate lines.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <regex.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        int             len;
        char            *cp;
        char            *token;
        regex_t         preg;
        regmatch_t      match;

        if (regcomp(&preg, argv[1], REG_EXTENDED) != 0) {
                return 0;
        }

        for (cp = argv[2]; *cp != '\0'; cp += len) {
                len = (regexec(&preg, cp, 1, &match, 0) == 0) ? match.rm_eo : strlen(cp);
                token = malloc(len);
                strncpy(token, cp, len);
                printf("%s\n", token); 
        }

        return 0;
}
```